# 4 Layer PCB stackup (components on both sides)

Tags: pcb, stack-up

I am in the process of designing a 4 layer PCB (components placed on both sides) with some specific constrains. I need to use the top layer as Ground plate and bottom layer as a signal layer. The combinations I think would make sense for my design are the following:

**A**
Top - GND,
Inner 1 - Signal & PWR,
Inner 2 - GND,
Bottom - Signal

**B**
Top - GND plate,
Inner 1 - Signal,
Inner 2 - PWR plate,
Bottom - Signal

**C**
Top - GND plate,
Inner 1 - Signal & PWR,
Inner 2 - GND plate,
Bottom - Signal & PWR

What are the advantages and disadvantages of above stackups?

Is there a more suitable stackup for my requirements: 4 layer PCB (components placed on both sides), Top layer should be GND plate and Bottom layer should carry signals.

The main components on the top side is an 120MHz MCU with a PCB antenna, Power Supply and on the bottom side a power meter IC. The requirements regarding top layer and bottom layer are due to space constrains.

The product will need to pass EMC testing (conducted and radiated emissions) according to EN standards.

Comment: I think the question really is missing an explanation why you have to use top layer for ground and bottom layer for signals. Is it for esthetics or is there a good reason? We don't know what signals you have onboard, if you have RF transmitters it might not pass any regulations even with 10 layer PCB, and in simpler case it may even pass with 2 layers. So what's on the board?

Comment: Basically: "Not B". B is bad because signals sandwiched between power and its return (gnd) planes, will experience a lot of interference from power supply currents. A and C are equivalent.

Comment: I added some more details about what is on top and bottom side.

Comment: How do space constraints lead to necessitating a very unusual L1 ground plane? I think the only reason I have personally heard about for such a design choice is if you mist satisfy very special shielding requirements for certain applications, but then I think both outer layers are usually a shield plane.